# Древовидно-рекурсивный процесс и его требования к памяти

Tags: рекурсия, sicp

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему при **увеличении** аргумента, передаваемого **древовидно-рекурсивной процедуре**, требования к памяти растет **линейно**? (В sicp дается объяснение: "...требования к памяти растут линейно, поскольку в каждой точке вычисления нам требуется запоминать только вершины, которые находятся выше нас по дереву", но все таки понять почему не смог).

Comment: Насколько понимаю, речь идет о том, что в конкретный момент времени процесс находится только в одной ветви, и поэтому максимальное требование к памяти зависит от длины этой ветви.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Нашел ответ, думаю многим, кто не знает, будет понятно:*

**Однократная *(линейная)*** рекурсия **образует глубокий стек** вызовов единичной ширины и быстро заполняет стек. Время работы программы до переполнения стека ничтожно мало.

**Двукратная *(древовидная)*** рекурсия **наоборот образует широкий стек** вызовов, ширина которого растет экспоненциально. Количество экземпляров рекурсивной функции растет лавинообразно. Это приводит к резкому замедлению работы программы. **При этом размер стека программы растет линейно с ростом глубины стека.**

Так вызов функции Fib (50) *(вычисление 50-ого числа Фибоначчи)* повлечет вызов 2^50 = 1 Пентабайт экземпляров Fib, в то время как стек программы будет максимально содержать 50·(2+4)=300 байт.